# JQuery to populate select list based on another select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 selects, one for states and one for cities, when the user selects the state the cities dropdown must be populated.

It seems it is working fine, when selecting the state you can see how the select is populated and you can select a city, however, if I revise the source code for the html I can not see any code (RMB View source code) and the selected value is not send to process the form.

My HTML

```
<select name="state" id="state" >
  <option value="1">State One</option>
  <option value="2">State Two</option>
  <option value="3">State Three</option>
</select>

<select name="city" id="city">
</select>
```

My JQuery (Got from a tutorial and adapted)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var list_target_id = 'city';
  var list_select_id = 'state';
  var initial_target_html = '';
  $('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {
    var selectvalue = $(this).val();
    $('#'+list_target_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
    if (selectvalue == "") {
     $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
    } else {
     $.ajax({url: 'cities.php?idc='+selectvalue,
     success: function(output) {
       //alert(selectvalue);
       $('#'+list_target_id).html(output);
     }});
    }
 });
});
```

The cities.php (here I read data from a DB, however, here is a simple example)

```
<?
   //these are the city values 
   echo '<option value="0">Select...</option>';
   echo '<option value="1">1</option>';
   echo '<option value="2">2</option>';
?>
```

Any ideas whats wrong? I can not get the values from cities.

Any help... thank you!

Comment: What's the value of the output?

Comment: The same htlm, no changes.

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitthk/yLLaa2rz/) for your scenario. I am using `$('#myForm').serialize()` to serialize the form.  It seems to work. If it doesn't in your case -I would like to see how are you posting your form then?

Comment: @amitthk no luck, using serialize shows the correct value in the page but if I process the form, the value is missing, I am posting the form, all the values are there but the city.

Comment: @amitthk What I was missing was to use serilize and open the url to process the form. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just serialize and open the URL to process the form:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

 $('#submit').click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = 'processTheForm.php?'+$('#myForm').serialize();
 })

  var list_target_id = 'city';
  var list_select_id = 'state';
  var initial_target_html = '';
  $('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {
    var selectvalue = $(this).val();
    $('#'+list_target_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
    if (selectvalue == "") {
     $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
    } else {
     $.ajax({url: 'cities.php?idc='+selectvalue,
     success: function(output) {
       //alert(selectvalue);
       $('#'+list_target_id).html(output);
     }});
    }
 });
});
```